# Showing $x\in \overline{A}$ if and only if every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$ 'directly'?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of a topological space $X$. It can be shown that $x\in \overline{A}$ if and only if every open set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$.

I can prove this by proving the contrapositive:
$x\notin \overline{A}$ if and only if there exists an open set $U$ containing $x$ that does not intersect $A$.

But is this the only way to prove this theorem? That is, can it only be shown using the contrapositive statement, or is there a more 'direct' way to prove it?

Comment: Could you please tell us what definition you're using for the closure? My definition of $\bar A$ is: "$\bar A$ is the set of all $x$ such that every open $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$". But this is identical to your first sentence, so there is literally nothing to prove. Maybe you are using another definition?

Comment: Is your definition perhaps that $\bar A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$?

Comment: For a "if and only if" theorem, it is not obvious to me what the contrapositive is. There are chances you can write your very same demonstration slighty differently and it will look like the "direct" proof you're looking for.

Comment: For brevity let $V$ be the family of open sets that contain $x.$ The assertion $x\not \in \bar A\iff \exists U\in V\;(U\cap A=\phi)$ is exactly equivalent to  $x\in \bar A \iff \forall U\in V\;(U\cap V \not =\phi).$

Comment: @KennyWong Sorry for the delay in replying, I was away for a few days. Yes that is the definition I use for $\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining $\overline{A}  =\bigcap\{C \subseteq X \text {closed}: A \subseteq C\}$
(the smallest closed set containing $A$ as a subset):

Let $x \in \overline{A}$ and let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x$. If $U \cap A = \emptyset$ then $A \subseteq X\setminus U$, and the latter set is closed, so $\overline{A} \subseteq X\setminus U$, in this definition. Contradiction, as witnessed by $x$. So $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Suppose $x$ has the neighbourhood intersection property. Let $C$ be a closed set that contains $A$. If $x \notin C$, then $X \setminus C$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ that misses $A$, which cannot be. So $x \in C$, and as $C$ was arbitrary closed around $A$,  $x \in \overline{A}$.

Pretty direct I'd say. We need small proofs by contradiction, but this is inherent to the statement, I think. To show $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$, we either have to find a concrete point that witnesses it or assume the opposit to make progress.

Comment: your explanation is pretty clear! Although I still have a doubt as to why necessarily does the statement needs to mention that $U$ should be an Open set? would the theorem still hold true if $U$ were closed sets? As in: "$x\in \overline{A}$ If and only if every closed set $U$ containing $x$ intersects $A$".

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the definition of $\overline{A}$ to be the union of $A$ with the limit points of $A$. We can write a very clean direct proof using nets. One direction is easy: if $x\in \overline{A}$, then any open set containing $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $A$. If $x\in A$, this is obvious, so let $x$ be a limit point of $A$. Then, there is some net $\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}}\subseteq A$ such that for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is an $\alpha\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\beta\geq \alpha$ implies $x_{\beta}\in U$. Clearly, this implies that for this given $U$, $x_{\alpha}\in U$ (since $\alpha\geq \alpha$), so $U\cap A$ must be nonempty.

Now, if every open set containing $x$ has a nonempty intersection with $A$, then for the family $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in \mathcal{A}}$ of neighborhoods of $x$ with $U_{\beta}\subseteq U_{\alpha}$ iff $\beta\geq \alpha$, we consider a net $\langle x_{\alpha}\rangle_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}$ such that $x_{\alpha}\in U_{\alpha}\cap A$. Then, for any neighborhood $U_{\alpha}$ of $x$, $x_{\beta}\in U_{\alpha}$ for all $\beta\geq \alpha$, so $x_{\alpha}\to x$. Thus, $x$ is a limit point of $A$, so $x\in \overline{A}$.